# MySQL: Creating a dataset with multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

I have different MySQL SELECT queries, all with different where statements. These produce totals, unique totals, totals of a certain type.

So for-instance:

```
Loc    | total | unique | missing

London | 10 | 5 | 2

New York |20 |10 |5
```

Currently I am running each of these Select queries separately, but I'd rather run them all at once. Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Something like:

```
SELECT
    Location
    Count(total)
    SELECT 
        count(unique)
    FROM
        .. my tables..
    WHERE
        .. where clause for unique part ..
    GROUP BY
        unique
FROM
    .. my tables ..
WHERE
    .. where clause for total part ..
GROUP BY
    total
```

Comment: Post the two queries you want to combine -- your psuedo-SQL is useless because the issue is abstracted so much there's nothing to glean from it.

Comment: The difficult part of your example is that SQL doesn't allow for table names to be represented by variables in an SQL statement. For that, you're into the province of stored procedures or script logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. For anyone else trying to get to grips with this, my eventual solution was:

```
SELECT
   Geo,
   total,
   SUM(unique) as unique
FROM
   (SELECT
      Geo,
      COUNT(total) AS total,
      0 unique,
    FROM
      -- my tables --
    WHERE
      -- where clause for totals --
    GROUP BY 
      Geo)
  UNION
    (SELECT
      Geo,
      0 total,
      COUNT(unique) AS unique,  
     FROM
       -- my tables --
     WHERE 
       -- where clause for unique --
     GROUP BY
       Geo)
) as tmptable
GROUP BY 
   Geo
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps what you want is a UNION

```
SELECT * from table where...
UNION
SELECT * from table where...
```

Obviously the columns returned from each query need to be the same.

Comment: Ahh, there's the problem, the initial query doesn't have columns that the others have. Can I do something like `missed=0` for the initial table that doesn't contain them?

Comment: Yes, `select null, x from table1 union select y, z from table2` is perfectly acceptable. As long as the row count matches in all the queries, you can do a union.

Comment: They don't need the same column names, but they need the same set of fields (number and type) in the same order - you can use NULLs or values in those positions if you need to.

Comment: Thanks, that's partly worked, but I seem now have two rows for each location, one with the total, and the other with the missed. How do I group them back together to get one row containing both?

Answer (score 0):

I expect a subquery (or several) is in order.

```
select location, (select count(total)  
                  from totalTable
                  where totalTable.location = locationTable.location) as total,
                 (select count(uniqe)
                  from uniqeTable
                  where uniqeTable.location = locationTable.location) as uniqe,
                 (select count(missing)
                  from missingTable
                  where missingTable.location = locationTable.location) as missing
from locationTable
where locationCriteria = searchCriteria
```

You can reference the same table in multiple subqueries, if necessary - just try to join them on ids, preferrably on something that's properly indexed.  Obviously the where clauses will have to be adjusted as necessary.